# Java JDBC "JdbcOdbcDriver" restriction

Tags: java, jdbc

I have just started getting familiar with JAVA JDBC. When I am trying to compile the below code in Eclipse,I am getting an error. I hope I will get some help here. Error is mentioned below the code.

```
import java.sql.*;
import sun.jdbc.odbc.*;

public class JdbcDriver {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException
    {
        JdbcOdbcDriver d = new JdbcOdbcDriver();
        System.out.println("Drivers are loaded");
        //register driver
     DriverManager.registerDriver(d);
        System.out.println("Driver is registered");
        //Establish connection with Oracle DB
        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:oradsn","Scott", "Tiger");
    if(con!=null)
        System.out.println("Connection is Established");
    else
        System.out.println("Connection is Fail");
        //create statement object for sending query to DB

    Statement st= con.createStatement();
    System.out.println("Statement object is created");
    //use statement object to execute the query
    String nss= "INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES(90,"IT","KPHB")";
    int i=st.executeUpdate(nss);
    System.out.println(i+"rec are inserted");
    //close the connection
    con.close();
    st.close();
    }
    }
```

Errors in console:

> **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:    Access restriction: The type JdbcOdbcDriver is not
>   accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar    **Access restriction: The constructor
>   JdbcOdbcDriver() is not accessible due to restriction on required
>   library C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar     Access restriction: The
>   type JdbcOdbcDriver is not accessible due to restriction on required
>   library C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar     Syntax error on tokens,
>   delete these tokens   at JdbcDriver.main(JdbcDriver.java:8)****

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do not use `sun` classes directly

Comment: Also the JDBC-ODBC Bridge is removed in Java 8. You should not use it anymore

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: In any case instead of `new`ing it, you should use `Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver")` to load it. It registers itself, so there is also zero reason to call `DriverManager.registerDriver` (which should only called by JDBC drivers initializing themselves). And if you want to connect to an Oracle database, you should really use the Oracle JDBC driver instead.